# Parsing different queries with same parser anorm

Tags: scala, anorm

I was trying to parse some different SQL queries using one anorm parser.
Some of the queries will return `a,b,c` as their result. Eventually, one of the query will return
`a,b,c,d,e`.

The result is tightly coupled to a return object called Obj with definition like:

```scala
case class Obj(a:Int,b:String,c:String,d:Option[String],e:Option[Double]
```

The parsing is done using :

```scala
val parser = Macro.namedParser[Obj](ColumnNaming.SnakeCase)
SQL("""select a,b,c .....further query""").on("a"->a).as(parser *)
SQL("""select a,b,c,d,e .... further query""").on("a"->a).as(parser *)
```

**Can I get the parser to avoid looking up for `d,e` in first case.**

I want to make both the queries work and the result to be parsed under same object.
As its a legacy codebase and the object is used at multiple places for parsing.. I would prefer to avoid to map all other queries to some other object and then copy the values there with None in `d,e` fields.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `Macro.namedParser` but if this doesn't work I assume that you have to explicitly returns `NULL` like `SELECT a,b,c, NULL as d, NULL as e` in your queries.

Comment: Another way is to do have different parser/case-class but provide an implicit conversion from one to the other

Comment: @GaëlJ thanks. 1st one would do the work!